# Android Permissions: Where is "Don't Ask Again" stored?

Tags: android-permissions

Once a user denies a permission and checks the "Don't Ask Again" box, you can never grant permissions in the future.

I checked all files in /data/data/MYAPP and below but I don't see it.
**Where do they hide this setting?**

Answer (score 1):

If the user checks the "Don't ask again" box then `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` will return false.

If this property is false you can show your own custom message box to the user. You can navigate them to their phone settings from this custom pop up. I think this is how google maps handles it at least

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java

Look at section "Request the permissions you need"

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it doesn't address my question. My device is rooted: if I could just find that setting, I could kill the beast.

Comment: Oh, I understand now, yikes. I would go digging in the android source code

Comment: Thanks, but digging into the source sounds like an impossibly difficult task - I wouldn't even know what to search for. I guess "Don't Ask Again" might be a start but I have little hope that would work. As a workaround, I tell the user to set the permissions manually using Settings->Apps->MYAPP->permissions, but I fear that would go over the heads of non-savvy users.

Comment: https://www.guidearea.com/granted-denied-and-permanently-denied-permissions-in-android/ 

This is a handy guide on how to display a snackbar that leads to the specific settings, when user has clicked "don't display again"